# Why visual studio cannot load symbols stored before?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, dump, debug-symbols

I have the following strange (at least for me) situation.

1. I created simple console application in `D:\Test` folder.
   Code is the following

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Dumps hello world !");
       int i = 5 + 5;
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```
2. Build solution and copy exe file into another folder `D:\Test2`. Run application from that folder, create dump file (using task manager), open this dump with visual studio, click "Debug with Mixed". Visual Studio is able to load symbols and i can analyze dump file from visual studio. Everything is fine

Now i want the following 
**a) modify current source code in folder `D:\Test` 

b) be able to analyze dump files for old exe file in folder `D:\Test2`.** 
 
So, to accomplish this i did backup for old .pdb file. I copied it into `D:\StoredSymbols` folder

3. Change source code to following

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Dumps hello world !");
       Console.WriteLine("Some minor changes");
       int i = 5 + 5;
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```
4. Run an old exec file from `D:\Test2`, make process dump, open it with visual studio, click "Debug with Mixed". As expected, Visual studio tries to load symbols from `D:\test` folder and cannot do it as .pdb file already corresponds to new exe file, not old.
5. So i set new path for .pdb file - `D:\StoredSymbols` but visual studio still cannot analyze dump file ! 
    
   WHY ?? 
   And what should i do to accomplish my **tasks** ? That is screenshot

[image]

Here is my Debug-->Modules screenshot 

[image]

Comment: So actually you changed the pdb file in your side, am I right? If so,how about debugging your app after you disable the option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

On the attached screenshot it says that it skipped loading symbols for `mscorlib.dll` and it is saying the reason ('Just My Code').

I don't think you are asking for those symbols. You want to load yours. If you check `Debug->Modules` and `Symbol Load Information` (under context menu) then you will probably see the info that "PDB does not match image". As far as I know VS require symbols to come from the same build as the image so there's no way to overcome this unless, you fake the symbols. This can be done in either using R# (paid) or dotPeek (free). dotPeek comes with a symbol server that serves PDBs on demand.

Basically you add dotPeek symbol server as a Symbol Server to your VS and it will generate PDB as needed.

I've recorded a short tut on how this can be done: [Debugging without source code with dotPeek Symbol Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7spm6C2j30)

Comment: Thank you Pawel for response. "will probably see the info that "PDB does not match image". Actually i do not see such message. I have updated question with modules screenshot

Comment: that's a bit strange. I'll check this case one more time later today

Comment: I redid those steps again and although I get the "Source Not Available" screen, when I switch frame to my code I get the source code (yet not an exact match) as they differ. What is your call stack when you see this error? Are you showing a method in your own codebase?

Comment: Thank you again Pawel for your efforts and help. Actually i do not understand your questions. Visual Studio does not ask me about source code, and i do not see any screens "Source not available". Actually that is strange ... How visual studio is going to analyze dump without sources ?

Comment: @Disappointed, What about this issue in your side? Generally we can debug using the disassembly of the modules if we can’t find the source files, but if the PDB doesn't exactly match the version of the DLL it usually refuses to load it.